# Typescript passing an Abstract Class as Generic constraint and construct it

Tags: typescript

I'm using the [apollo RESTDataSource](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-datasource-rest/src/RESTDataSource.ts)

I see it is an `abstract class`

I'm creating a function to instantiate this `DataSource` (which are normal `Class`es), to pass back to the user to allow them to call a specific function on the `DataSource` - essentially the responsibility of constructing the DataSource is with my function, but I allow the caller to specify which method to call.

```js
const httpCaller = <TRequest, TResponse, DataSource extends typeof RESTDatasource>(
  args: TRequest,
  dataSourceConstructor: DataSource,
  httpExecutor: (ds: DataSource, args: TRequest) => Promise<TResponse>
) {

  const dataSourceFactory = (args: TRequest) => {
    const ds = new dataSourceConstructor();
    ds.initialize({ context: {}, cache })
    return httpExecutor(ds, args);
  }

  // this const gets passed down into other functions and at some point (the right point it gets called)

  doingOtherStuff(args, dataSourceFactory);
}
```

Currently it complains that `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.ts(2511)` which, I get, but I thought, that if `DataSource extends` then that doesn't necessarily mean that `DataSource` is an abstract... I've tried doing `& { new(...args: any[]) => any }`, however, that just shuts up the error on `new dataSourceConstructor()` line, but when I pass `MyCustomDataSource`, it complains...

I've read a few things, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this suffice?

```
const httpCaller = <TRequest, TResponse, DataSource extends RESTDatasource>(
  args: TRequest,
  dataSourceConstructor: { new(...args: any[]): DataSource },
  httpExecutor: (ds: DataSource, args: TRequest) => Promise<TResponse>
) {
```

Comment: almost, I changed the type arg to `DataSource extends RESTDatasource>` and the `=>` you put needs to be a `:` and then yeah - it worked! Nice one!

Comment: Glad I could help. I fixed your remarks in case someone ends up here